# Arraylist value changes automatically KOTLIN

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have an arraylist inside another arraylist , when i enter values,  value of the previous arraylist automatically changes to last entered value.

Code is as follows

Question.class

```
data class Question(
var id: String,
var question: String,
var correct: String,
var answer: ArrayList<String>
)
```

MainActivity

```
        answers.add("1234")
        answers.add("234")
        questions.add(Question("1","1","1",answers))
        Log.d("12345",questions.toString())

        answers.clear()
        answers.add("5678")
        answers.add("789")
        questions.add(Question("2","2","2",answers))
        Log.d("12345",questions.toString())
```

o/p

D/12345: [Question(id=1, question=1, correct=1, answer=[1234, 234])]

D/12345: [Question(id=1, question=1, correct=1, answer=[5678, 789]), Question(id=2, question=2, correct=2, answer=[5678, 789])]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have one list of answers here. Each question gets a reference to that single list. Instead, you should create a new list of answers for each question. To understand this better, I suggest you read about references in Kotlin.